# Mass upload of file to records

Tags: data-import

I have a bunch of certificates which are scanned as images that needs to be uploaded into the correct record to be attached in the Certificate file field.  Can this be 'imported' like how you can import data into CIVICRM contacts ?  Thanks.

Clement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While Aidan's answer is correct that it's not hard to code a solution, you might be asking if a solution has already been coded.  If so, I'm afraid the answer is no.

Answer (score 3):

This should be fairly simple to script using the Attachment api.  For docs, go to https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/api#docs and select Attachment as the entity which has an example of using create with a custom field.

[image]